# mockito spy doesn't act as I expect

Tags: java, spring, testing, junit, mockito

I'm trying to use spy mockito in my test. Here is my code:

```
@Spy
AddressServiceImpl service;

@InjectMocks
AddressController controller;

@Test
void loadAddresses(){
    User user = new User();
    Address address1 = new Address(user,"2345", "5678", "7890", "test@gmail.com", "street");
    Address address2 = new Address(user,"9876", "7654", "6543", "test2@gmail.com", "avenue");

    service.save(address1);
    service.save(address2);

    List<Address> searchAdress = new ArrayList<>();

    given(service.findByEmailContaining(anyString())).willCallRealMethod();

    searchAdress = controller.loadAddress(address1);
    }
```

And in my controller:

```
private AddressService addressService;

public List<Address> loadAddress(Address address){
    List<Address> theAddresses = new ArrayList<>();


    theAddresses = addressService.findByEmailContaining("%"+ address.getEmail() + "%");

    return theAddresses;
```

}

I expect that controller searches in my saved addresses(address1,address2) by address1.getEmail() and returns the address1 object. but it dosen't return any thing.

In fact service.save(address1) retuurn null object instead of adress1.

this method call save method from JPA repository.

Comment: Just to be sure, your AddressServiceImpl has a default constructor, your spy object isnt null and such things? And note: you want to call the REAL method for finding, but adding the addresses ... not going to the real methods?!

Comment: AddressServiceImpl has an empty costructor, It works correctly in controller method. addressService is a real method, I edited the question and add the defination of that.

Comment: what does the `service.save()` method do?

Comment: In real, This method saves the object to database through JPA repository. I want to mock these methods: save two objects in database and search the email on them.

Comment: You haven't stubbed `service.save()`, so it is still going to call the real method. In fact, your `given` statement is completely redundant because the default behavior of Mockito spies is to call the real method.